# Finding pattern

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

Just a puzzle.
\begin{matrix}
        2 & 9 & ? \\
        11 & 33 & 66 \\
        8 & 3 & 27 \\
        \end{matrix}
The options are $35$, $40$, $45$, $55$.
$45$ is false.
I thought the answer was $15$ since they are of the form $3a + b = c$, but there isn't a $15$.
EDIT: It's not a problem from a math test so I think that the pattern (if there is one at all!) should be an "easy" one.
EDIT again: My friend said he was not sure if 45 is wrong. Maybe he is wrong on another problem. I think 45 is the right answer!

Comment: Every composite number in the matrix can be built by the primes in the matrix.

Comment: @Chou But then no answer leaves this property true, since the only primes are $2,3,11$, and they are all divisible by $5$.

Comment: Yes! Just want to type :) Finding a way to involve 5

Comment: Where does this originate from?

Comment: I guess 40 is very likely the choice; for if $A$ denotes the given matrix then $A_{31}$ and $A_{33}$, which both have a subscript equal to $3$, both have a prime in $A$ appearing exactly $3$ times. So $A_{13}$ should also have a prime appearing exactly $3$ times. But only $40 = 5 \times 2^{3}$ has such a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of all digits of each row is always 20.

**Second row:** $1+1+3+3+6+6=20$

**Third row:** $8+3+2+7=20$

Then:

**First row:** $2 + 9 +a +b = 11+a+b = 20 \Rightarrow a+b = 9$

where $10a + b$ is the number to be placed in the position $(1,3)$.

This is only possible if the number to be placed is $45$; in fact $a=4, b=5$ and $a+b=9$.

Comment: Yes this is a neat pattern. Maybe the problem itself is "wrong".

Comment: Do you know the solution of this test?

Comment: Nope, I don't know the "solution".

Comment: ok. I asked just to understand why you wrote that $45$ is false.

Comment: It's a problem from a test my friend took some time ago online. He chose 45 and it was wrong. And that's all I know :(

Comment: can you share with us the site where you find this test? Maybe this can help us

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23178/discussion-between-leafpile-and-the-candyman).

Comment: He said it was a "logic" test for some program... All other questions appear "natural" except this one. I am thinking maybe this one is "wrong" itself

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the pattern is that every number in the box can be formed by adding, subtracting, multiplying, or dividing two numbers from columns other than the column that number resides in. Then the answer would be 35.